# Cassandra keyspace not replicating

Tags: cassandra

I have setup a Cassandra cluster with 2 nodes in same datacenter. The cluster is up and running fine as can be seen by the command "nodetool status"

```
Datacenter: dc1
===============    
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.0.0.4   258.39 KB  256          ?       39c5c07f-1049-4292-95b6-c30fe1220d40  rack1
UN  10.0.0.12  270.68 KB  256          ?       93d8ddbc-af01-4849-a5e6-589ca6ee6d96  rack1
```

Then I created a new keyspace using the following command:-

```
CREATE KEYSPACE simplex WITH replication = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 2};
```

However the keyspace is only getting created on the machine where I execute the "create keyspace...." command and not getting replicated to the other node. There aren't any errors in the log file. Can someone please let me know what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Schema agreement can take some times. Did you retry to log into the other machine and check the schema to see if the keyspace was created ?

Comment: Don't think it is an issue with time. Even after 4-5 hours not replicated.

Comment: did you found a solution for this issue?